# Queue for ignored local notifications?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, uilocalnotification, badge

My question has to do with what happens when the user ignores multiple local notification.  In my testing, it appears that iOS 5.1 (perhaps earlier too) passes only the last ignored notification to the app and discards all of the previous ignored notifications.

With my app (and I'm sure many others out there) the user may not launch the app with every notification and thus the possibility exists that there may be several unacknowledged notifications before the user launches the app.  The reason this is important to me is that I am trying to place an accurate badge on one of my apps tabs to reflect the number of fired but not yet acknowledged notifications.

Has anyone solved this problem?  Apple's phone app keeps an accurate badge for missed calls, but of course they have more capabilities than we do. Unless I have to, I don't want to resort to changing from an numeric badge to something else like an exclamation point.

Regards,

-- John

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3201049/792677 ?

Comment: Yeah, I saw that.  I was hoping for a better solution in iOS > 4.

Comment: check my answer here - this might help you :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962054/iphone-incrementing-the-application-badge-through-a-local-notification/15461328#15461328